# How to ignore the type comparison for MongoDB $eq aggregation operator for numbers?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The `$eq` operator compares both value and type in MongoDB as described in https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq.

Is there any methods to ignore the type comparison when the two expressions are both numbers?

Here is an example, the dataset is like

```
[
  {
    "field1": {
      "$numberDecimal": "0.99"
    },
    "field2": 0.99
  }
]
```

The query return no documents as the types of field1 and field2 are different. However a match in this case is what I expected.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$field1",
          "$field2"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

A `$convert` before the `$eq` operation may work in this example, but the types of the two fields might be a string in the production environment, and I don't want to do the conversion if it is a string type.

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/v7XaiQHuINr

Comment: How about convert both to string: like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eOLia1QF76T)?

Comment: Do you mind giving us more details about your background story or intention? A simple match will not persist the type conversion from string to double. So nimrod serok's idea of converting to the same datatype will work and will not affect your persisted record.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `$set` stage to convert the field to a decimal if they are numbers  in a first step. If a field is not numeric, its value is used as is.

Afterwards, the comparison will work und you can removed the additional fields in an `$unset` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      field1Normalized: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $isNumber: "$field1"
          },
          then: {
            $toDecimal: "$field1"
          },
          else: "$field1"
        }
      },
      field2Normalized: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $isNumber: "$field2"
          },
          then: {
            $toDecimal: "$field2"
          },
          else: "$field2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$field1Normalized",
          "$field2Normalized"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "field1Normalized",
      "field2Normalized"
    ]
  }
])
```

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c5hGfKCON4G) to test.

As @Joe mentioned in the comments, you can include the `$cond` in the `$match` stage to get rid of the temporary fields.

Comment: You could put the $cond inside the $eq if you don't want temporary fields in the doc

Comment: @Joe, thank you - I've included a hint in the answer. I'd hope that MongoDB optimizes the pipeline anyway so it is more or less a question of readability.